# Shortcut or function to un- or de-emphasize without manual selection

Tags: org-mode, formatting

The function `org-emphasize` puts formatting on a region, e. g. `*` at the beginning end end of a bold sentence or word.

To remove the bold attribute I can mark the same region, execute `M-x org-emphasize` and hit space.

**Question:** Is there a way to remove emphasis on a sentence without the need to mark the region?

**Thoughts:** Maybe it is possible to detect the next and previous emphasis marker and delete them. As an alternative: How would I mark the text between the next and previous emphasis marker in a function?

Comment: How would you deal with `this is *bold* and that is *bolder*` when point is say after the `h` of `that`?

Comment: Good question. One option would be to delete the most adjacent `*` and format the whole text in bold: `*bold and that is bolder*`. Another option to parse the whole paragraph and ask for a selection of the occurence (1 or 2) and delete the corresponding formatting. But I have absolutely no clue how to do either in elisp. :-/ If a function selects the region between the two `*` then there would be some visual feeback to move the cursor. What do you think?

Comment: How often do you have to do that? For the few times that I would make any use of such a function, and given that it might require some somewhat complicated logic to deal with possibly ambiguous situations, I would forego the function and just delete the emphasis characters by hand. That would allow me to tailor the response to the exact situation, so I could resolve ambiguities in real time. IOW, IMO it's not worth automating.  OTOH, if you are looking to learn some lisp, it might be a good exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens):

```
(require 'smartparens)
(require 'smartparens-config)   
(define-key smartparens-mode-map (kbd "C-<backspace>") 'sp-unwrap-sexp)
(define-key smartparens-mode-map (kbd "M-<backspace>") 'sp-backward-unwrap-sexp)
```

For example:

```
This is *bold* and th|at is *bolder*.
```

Pressing `M-<backspace>` unwraps the word "bold". Pressing `C-<backspace>` unwraps the word "bolder". Also, to make a word `*bold*` (`/italic/` etc.), type `*` once and the the cursor is wrapped automatically.

Alternatively, you can try the following command (lightly tested).

```lisp
(defun toggle-emphasis ()
  (interactive)
  (save-match-data
    (if (and (org-in-regexp org-emph-re 2)
             (not (region-active-p)))
        (let ((beg (match-beginning 3))
              (end (match-end 4)))
          (when (and (>= (point) (1- beg))
                     (<= (point) (1+ end)))
            (save-excursion
              (goto-char end)
              (delete-char 1)
              (goto-char beg)
              (delete-char 1))))
      (call-interactively #'org-emphasize))))

(global-set-key [remap org-emphasize] #'toggle-emphasis)
```

Pressing `C-c C-x C-f` should work as usual with the cursor outside the marked area (see below). Otherwise the word "bold" is unwrapped.

```
This is *bold* and...
       ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I will check it out on the weekend.

Comment: I whish I had known smartparens before. This makes formatting text a breeze. I chose `M-<backspace>` for `sp-unwrap-sexp` and `S-<backspace>` for `sp-backward-unwrap-sexp` because it feels mor mnemonic with Shift being on the left side (back) and Alt being on the right (forward).